# $POST Image File Not Uploading If to Large

Tags: php, html

In my code:

```
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"     method="post" name="changer" class="login" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;">
  <h3>Avatar: </h3>

    <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
    <input value="Update Avatar" type="submit">
     </form>
```

It has a max upload size for an image of around 1 mb, meaning whenever I try to get these files after I submit the form, it doesn't find any file if the upload is greater than 1 mb. How can i increase the upload max size?

To read File:

```
   if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {
   }else if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size']== 0){ echo "empty";}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the  post_max_size  and  upload_max_filesize  in php.ini
such that

```
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
```

Comment: If your using nginx then you need to add something like ``client_max_body_size 100m;`` into the http block of your configuration. If your using another web server that also utilizes PHP-FPM, then there might be a different setting as well.

Comment: It still didn't work. It thinks the file size is 0b after I submit the form with a 2.8 mb picture.

Answer (score 1):

As KNaito said you need to specify your max sizes in you php.ini. You can also try to do this from within your script like so

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '16M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

Try increasing the following values in your php.ini file, for example:

```
memory_limit = 99M
max_execution_time = 300
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 24M
```

On the Grid, once you make those changes and save the file, that's all you need to do. The Apache web server doesn't need to be restarted (and, to be clear, you don't have that level of access on the Grid platform).

**Additional information**

If the upload_max_filesize is larger than post_max_size, you must increase post_max_size so that it is bigger than upload_max_size.

If the value of post_max_size is larger than memory_limit, you must increase memory_limit so that it is larger than post_max_size.